# How many solutions has the equation $e^z=z$?

Tags: complex-analysis

> How many solutions does the complex equation $$e^z=z$$ have ?

Can we somehow use that this equation implies $z=\ln(z)$ and if this is possible, how do we deal with the infinite many branches of the complex logarithm ?

Is $2$ the number of solutions ?

Comment: Also: [Are there any simple ways to see that $e^z-z=0$ has infinitely many solutions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/137927/42969)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution of the equation is given in terms of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)
$$z=-W_k(-1)$$ As you will see, there is no real solutions and, in the complex domain, there is an  infinite number of solutions, each of them corresponding to the $k^{th}$ branch of Lambert function.